# AM/PM is not getting from NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

The time format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a" usually gives date string like 2016-01-22 13:01 PM

But I am not getting AM/PM part when the 24-Hour is ON on device and by using the following code(ie. used different time zone).
the result for below code is 2016-01-22 13:01

```
NSDateFormatter* estDf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[estDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
estDf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
NSString *timeStr = [estDf stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

But I can get AM/PM part even if the 24-Hour is ON on device and using the following code (ie. using device time zone).
the result for below code is 2016-01-22 13:01 PM

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
NSString * timeStr = [dateformat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

My question is what I have to do in the first code snippet in this question to get AM/PM part along the date string

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Update your question with the actual output you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

The settings of the phone don't matter. To have the time in AM/PM format, you need to use `hh:mm`, to have the time in 24 hour format, you need to use `HH:mm` format.

Simply using capital H tells the format to switch between 24h and 12h formats.

Also the `a` in the format string will display the AM/PM.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question (or maybe I don't). I think the OP wants 12-hour time with AM/PM based on the format they are using. I think the question is why it works properly in the 2nd bit of code but not the first.

Comment: In some local 12 and  24 hour format matters a lot. for i.e in US local you are not able to get AM/PM if format was 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Using "aa" instead of just "a" forces AM/PM even when displaying 24-hour time.